# angular js: oauth2 implementation for rest ful api

Tags: angular, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement a oauth2 authentication for my angualar 2 web project. This project is solely depends on rest apis. All ng-oauth2 the packages I found needs a new login page for authentication. But I need restful authentication. I already setup a django server with ouath2 authentication.

So I need to call the authentication url as

```
mydomain.com/oauthlogin
```

with header values

```
Authorization: Bearer JnEmTyenQS54L6NZeJ4eVhcQ1DLDOa
```

Is there any package with these type of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You need to secure the routes that require an access token using Angular guard. The guard will check whether the application has the access token saved somewhere, e.g. in browser's session storage. If there is no token the guard, redirects the user to the OAuth2 `/auth` endpoint with all necessary request parameters.

After authentication, the OAuth2 server redirects the user back to your application to the specified redirect URL. So you need a route that will accept the request, extract and save all information from the URL and move to some other route (possibly stored in the `stage` parameter).

Then you need a custom `Http` service or `XhrBackend` service that will add the `Authorization` request header to XHR calls.

So you don't need any special library, just few more classes in your application.